# Angularjs img id post to database

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a recipe book with angularjs and i have chosen that when the user clicks on an img of the food they want to make, the id of that img tag is posted from a controller to a factory, where the factory makes a database query for a recipe matching the id.

Controller:

```
$scope.trigger = function(id){
    var id = id;
    recipeFactory.getIngredients(id)
        .then(function(returnedirecipe) {
            ingredientinfo=[
                (returnedirecipe[0].RecipeName),
                (returnedirecipe[0].RecipeDescription)
            ];
        }
}
```

Factory:

```
function recipeFactory($http){
    return {
        getIngredients : function(id){
        var promise=  $http.post("http://localhost:8080/angularcookbook/ajax/recipesdb.php", {RecipeName: id})
            .then(function (response) {
                var jsonResult = response.data;
                return jsonResult;
            })

            return promise;
        }
    }
}
```

This works all fine, I can display the data on the same file I've made the query on. My question is how could I return the query from the factory to a new controller? The goal would be to display the recipe on a separate html file with it's own controller.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to format the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help you:

http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-code-between-controllers-using-services.html

:)